# Why People like Owaisi get so much support in India? In spite of his hatred comments

Tags: india

People like [Owaisi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akbaruddin_Owaisi#Hate_Speech_at_Adilabad) always spread hatred comments and still get away.  Whereas any other religion political leader that would say the same would get thrashed by the media.

Comment: Can you provide some references to justify for "hatred comments"?

Comment: Seeing one side of the coin.

Comment: Because in India we have leftist media which hates Hinduism but any such acts go unreported and uncondemned by the media if dome by some Muslim community leader. Add to this we have many political parties who vie for Muslim vote bank to keep themselves in power.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indians have a tendency to be collectivist, and that makes it really easy for politicians to 'target' specific groups of people, it's all just pure pandering. They realize the ease with which you can gain power if you leverage these unified voting blocs. In this case, Owaisi sees it more beneficial for him to appease the Muslims - even if it means spewing hateful, nasty rhetoric against other groups of people, since his constituency has a clear Muslim majority.

By the way, not all media present the same narratives, there *are* news outlets which condemn Owaisi too, it all depends on who owns these media outlets (and their connections). If you see a news channel unreasonably criticising some personality, take a look at who owns the media, what are their motivations, what are their financial interests, who is financing them etc. Just follow the money.

Answer (score 4):

The same reason why [Yogi Adityanath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yogi_Adityanath) gets to become [Chief Minister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Chief_Ministers_of_Uttar_Pradesh) of [Uttar Pradesh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uttar_Pradesh) of India.

He has [banned beef](http://www.hindustantimes.com/opinion/adityanath-s-meat-ban-is-more-caste-based-than-just-a-devious-political-plan/story-sMcBzJ67OgjwgHnxloDLGM.html), is [killing Muslims](http://www.milligazette.com/print/issue/1-15-april-2011/3), and [what not](http://www.reuters.com/article/india-politics-religion-uttar-pradesh-hi-idUSKBN17Z0J2).

He and his henchmen are quite famous and popular for hate-speeches.

- http://www.indiatimes.com/news/india/yogi-adityanaths-men-telling-hindus-to-rape-dead-muslim-women-is-beyond-shocking-230679.html
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5WgcoTPCuTY
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7_L8HS4NBBg
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HbI2rqXJAtw

.

**So, the answer is**, because of the widespread communal attitude among general Indian citizens, and predisposition towards seeing **one side of the coin** (as same as this question).

- it stems from the lack of [Liberalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberalism).
- which stems from the lack or low-quality of education coupled with racism (casteism), and religious bigotry.

Comment: This has nothing to do with education. Polarization and bigotry is the same or even higher among highly educated; worldwide (Holy Inquisition was set up and run by THE most intellectual section of populace of Middle Age Europe. Anti-Semitism is far higher among university-educated leftists than average people)

Comment: @user4012, then, what is your reason?

Comment: general bad quality of two-legged primates calling themselves "homo sapient" seems an adequate explanation (we evolved with tribal loyalty and chauvinism as survival traits). AFAIR Chimps were observed exterminating neighboring troupes just for giggles (or territory).

Comment: @user4012, I think, "lack of Liberalism" is enough to describe.

Comment: @user4012 That's an interesting claim "Anti-Semitism is far higher among university-educated leftists than average people". Would you care to elaborate that with references? It looks like a claim from some of those people who try to undermine legitimate criticism of Israel by claiming that it is Anti-Semitic. Or people who think supporting Palestinian independence is same as Anti-Semitism.

Comment: Banning beef? How is it same as issuing threat to the Hindu community that if police force was removed for 15 minutes we 250 million Muslims will teach good lesson to 1 billion Hindus? Can you cite any examples of a minority community leader making such threats against majority community in any other country.

Comment: @RolenKoh, as I already said you are `seeing one side of the coin`. The OP is an illegal question in the first place. And, to answer your question: they can pass some comment on the face of imminent ethnic cleansing. As I said, don't make me say something more, as it will turn into a racist debate.

Comment: @anonymous: By imminent ethnic cleansing you mean to say the one that took place in Kashmir against Kashmiri Pundits?

Comment: @RolenKoh, show me your reference regarding Kashmiri Pundits. There is no historical record. This is a continuous lie propagated by Indian media as same as Bangladeshi migration is Assam. This is ethnic cleansing :  https://www.nytimes.com/2015/11/05/world/asia/hindu-mob-kills-another-indian-muslim-accused-of-harming-cows.html

Comment: @anonymous: When agenda has already been set then everything contradicting that agenda is a lie. But for your knowledge (which you already have) here are links https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exodus_of_Kashmiri_Hindus http://thediplomat.com/2016/01/the-persecution-of-kashmirs-minority-hindus/

Comment: @RolenKoh, and tell me where is it written that those Pundits were massacred.

Comment: @anonymous: Here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1998_Wandhama_massacre

Comment: @anonymous: And here: http://ikashmir.net/history/genocide.html

Comment: @anonymous: And here too: https://kashmirblogs.wordpress.com/genocide-of-kashmiri-pandits/

Comment: @anonymous: Oh and forgot here: http://www.indiandefencereview.com/news/kashmiri-pandits-offered-three-choices-by-radical-islamists/

Comment: @anonymous: And here as well: http://www.dailyo.in/politics/kashmiri-pandits-exodus-habbakadal-hizbul-mujahideen-yasin-malik-pakistan/story/1/8533.html

Comment: @RolenKoh, Wikipedia source tells about 10 persons. Regarding the rest, do you have any neutral source?

Comment: @anonymous: Yes most of the links are neutral. Now don't pretend that Hindus were not targeted in Kashmir genocide.

Comment: @RolenKoh, LOL. I am done with your chauvinism. Kindly, go to Quora and post answers there. You will find billions of votes.

Comment: @anonymous: Of course you are. Anything which contradicts your set agenda is either a lie or chauvinism.

Comment: @RolenKoh, If you are satisfied with your Indian newspapers, blogs, and minor reports, then go ahead. Do what you like to do. I don't have any problem. Bye.

Comment: @anonymous: It is question of truth not any newspaper. And Indian newspapers hardly reported anything on Kashmir genocide. Bye.